# how to handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app with user and events. Each user has several events. When a user wants to see a specific event he will get to this action:

```
def show
  begin
    @userEvents = current_user.event
    @event = @userEvents.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  
    redirect_to :controller => "main", :action => "index"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @event }
  end
end
```

If the event is not found for the user it means he played with the URL and the event he is trying to get does not belong to him. I want to either redirect him to the main page or just display the page with an error that the event is not found. If I try to run the code above this error fires:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in EventsController#show
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put *return* after redirect

```
begin
 @userEvents = current_user.event
 @event = @userEvents.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  
 redirect_to :controller => "main", :action => "index"
 return
end
```

Answer (score 18):

Calling `redirect_to` doesn't return from your action method which is why moving on to the `respond_to` block causes the `DoubleRenderError`. One way to fix that is with:

```
redirect_to :controller => "main", :action => "index" and return
```

However, a better solution might be to either [rescue from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) this exception declaratively or just let it propagate to the client. The former look like this:

```
class YourController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :dude_wheres_my_record

  def show
    # your original code without the begin and rescue
  end

  def dude_where_my_record
    # special handling here
  end
end
```

If you just let the exception fester the user will see the `public/404.html` page in production mode.

Comment: didn't quiet understand your solution... why should that rescue happen every time in the controller?.. i need it just in the show action. but thanks

Comment: The `rescue_from` is just a nicer way of dealing with common errors at times, allowing you to separate out concerns in your code. Of course it's not always better, hence the other two options :-)

Answer (score 5):

> In application controller, please write:

```
    rescue_from (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) { |exception| handle_exception(exception, 404) }

   protected

    def handle_exception(ex, status)
        render_error(ex, status)
        logger.error ex   
    end

    def render_error(ex, status)
        @status_code = status
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :template => "error", :status => status }
          format.all { render :nothing => true, :status => status }
       end
    end
```

> Create a page error.html.erb

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <%= t "errors.#{@status_code}.heading" %>
    <small><%= t "errors.#{@status_code}.subheading" %></small>
  </h1>
</div>
<p><%= t "errors.#{@status_code}.description" %></p>
<% if defined? root_path %>
  <%= link_to t(:return_to_home), root_path %>
<% end %>
```

> and in en.yml

```
en:
  errors:
    "404":
      description: "The page you are looking for does not exist!"
      heading: "Record not found"
      subheading: ""
```

Comment: Quick note, error.htm.erb should go inside the /views folder root.